# Query mongoose model using variable as key in nested document

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having some trouble using model.find to return a list of documents that match a variable condition within my nested schema. I am using node, express, and mongoose for this project.

Ideally I want to use a variable as the object key within the query so I can dynamically grab the day of the week and check the open hours. I haven't had any success so far in finding an answer for this online.

Here is my model.

```
const restaurantSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    coordinates: {
        latitude: { type: Number, required: true },
        longitude: { type: Number, required: true }
    },
  happy_hour: {
      sunday: {
          open: { type: Boolean },
          open_at: { type: Number },
          close_at: { type: Number }
      },
      monday: {
          open: { type: Boolean },
          open_at: { type: Number },
          close_at: { type: Number }
      },
      tuesday: {
          open: { type: Boolean },
          open_at: { type: Number },
          close_at: { type: Number }
      },
      wednesday: {
          open: { type: Boolean },
          open_at: { type: Number },
          close_at: { type: Number }
      },
      thursday: {
          open: { type: Boolean },
          open_at: { type: Number },
          close_at: { type: Number }
      },
      friday: {
          open: { type: Boolean },
          open_at: { type: Number },
          close_at: { type: Number }
      },
      saturday: {
          open: { type: Boolean },
          open_at: { type: Number },
          close_at: { type: Number }
      }
  }
});
```

Here is a snippet from the controller that is handling the logic for this express route. The snippet below has a static key called "Friday", but I want to dynamically get the day of the week and pass that in as a variable, something like $friday: { open: true } or what not.

```
exports.search = (req, res, next) => {
    const radius = req.query.radius || 5;
    const latitude = req.query.latitude;
    const longitude = req.query.longitude;
    const day = date.get_day();
    const minutes = date.get_minutes();
    console.log(query[day]);
    if ( latitude == undefined || longitude == undefined ) {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: "Missing longitude or latitude"
        })
    }
    Restaurant.find({ 
        hours: {
            friday: {
                open: true
            }
        }
    })
        .exec()
        .then(results => {
            res.status(200).json({
                data: results.map( result => {
```

Comment: Probably you can build the query as a string (using string interpolation) and then parse it as JSON: `query = JSON.parse("{hours: {``$day``: {open: true}}}")`

Comment: I am not familiar with the syntax ``$day`` in that statement. How does that work?

Comment: It is "String interpolation" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options to do that.

The query that mongoose expects, is just an object.

```
const query = { hours : {} };
hours[getTheCurrentDay()].open = true;

// Or with es6

const query = { hours : { [getTheCurrentDay()] : { open : true } };

// Or with pure string

const query = { `hours.${getTheCurrentDay()}.open` : true };

Restaurant.find( query ).exec()...
```

Comment: Are there any performance benefits to using any of these options?

Comment: Without making any perfs, I would say insignificant performance difference. What you should ask yourself though is which one is more readable for your code base.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var day = req.params.dayName;
var query = {};
query["hours"] = {[day] :true};
collection.find(query, function (err, item) { ... });
```

Comment: I had to change the query to {[day]: { open: true }} to work with my example above, but with that said the query returns the same structure as my schema with correct day, however, the query is returning no results. I definitely have some data in mongo that should be returned for this query. Any ideas? I noticed that the day was capitalized so I set it to lowercase and it had no effect.

Comment: console.log is showing the query as `{ hours: { wednesday: { open: true } } }` which is correct. I have restaurants in the database which have this set to true.